# Can we use Function which takes dynamic values for optional interface for java8

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, option-type

I am new to java 8 and trying to pass method names dynamically to get the values.

I have a `Request` request which has `getInput1()`, `getInput2()` methods. I can map the `Optional` statically like this:

```
void methodExecute(){ 
  Optional<Request> request = Optional.of(new Request()); 
  request.map(request::getInput1); //gives input1 value
  request.map(request::getInput2); //gives input2 value 
}
```

Can we do the same thing dynamically, if `"getInput1"` and `"getInput2"` method names are passed at runtime?

Below one is my approach. But it does not work.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function_WithExceptions<T, V,R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t,V v) throws E;
}

public class LambdaUtil<Input1, Input2> {
    public static <Input1,Input2, R, E extends Exception> 
                            Function_WithExceptions<Input1,Input2, R,E> rethrowFunction(Function_WithExceptions<Input1,Input2, R, E> function) throws E  {
        return (t,v) -> {
            try {
                return function.apply(t,v);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                throwActualException(exception);
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <E extends Exception> void throwActualException(Exception exception) throws E {
        throw (E) exception;
    }
}

public Function_WithExceptions getFunction(){
        Function_WithExceptions<Request, String,Object,Exception> requestObjParamFun = (reqObj,req)->MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(reqObj, req);
        return requestObjParamFun;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate `Function`s for getters dynamically, but don’t want every invocation resorting to Reflection, you can use the same back-end as the Java language method references:

```
static <T> Function<Request, T> reflect(String getterName, Class<T> resultType)
            throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType getter=MethodType.methodType(resultType);
    MethodHandle target = l.findVirtual(Request.class, getterName, getter);
    getter=target.type();
    try {
        return (Function)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "apply",
            MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
            getter.generic(), target, getter).getTarget().invokeExact();
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        throw new ReflectiveOperationException(ex);
    }
}
```

This can be used the same way as [Tagir’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32285644/2711488) but won’t use Reflection on `Function` invocations (*usually*; as it’s JRE specific, it may use Reflection if method references also use Reflection in a particular JRE implementation).

But, as with the Reflection approach, it must be used carefully as an erroneous use is not spotted at compile time but at runtime.

Comment: May i ask  how can we do ? if   it  is a method  with multiple params (varags)    ( reflection Method Type)     how it will be usage of LambdaMetaFactory doSomethig(String a , String b , int c)  any example for that ? is there any way to create dynamic @FunctionalInterface ?

Comment: @Saltuk the comment section is not meant for such complex questions. Just [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question. Don’t forget to include details about what you tried and what didn’t work.

Comment: ok sorry that .. here is what i am trying to do ..  i hope you have time .. thank you ...     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831119/java-lambdametafactory-method-call-with-multiple-vargs-to-avoid-reflection

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem can be solved like this:

```
static <T> Function<Request, T> reflect(String getterName, Class<T> resultType)
           throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Method method = Request.class.getMethod(getterName);
    return req -> {
        try {
            return resultType.cast(method.invoke(req));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Here we just use normal reflection API to get the method of `Request` class by its name and return the function which calls it. Usage example:

```
// Some test Request class
static class Request {
    public String getInput1() {return "aa";}
    public Integer getInput2() {return 1;}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Optional<Request> request = Optional.of(new Request());
    System.out.println(request.map(reflect("getInput1", String.class))); // Optional[aa]
    System.out.println(request.map(reflect("getInput2", Integer.class))); // Optional[1]
}
```