# Java LambdaMetaFactory Method call with multiple vargs to avoid Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, lambda-metafactory

I am currently using Java reflection

I don't have any  problem doing it with reflection . I learned about LambdaMetaFactory  has better performance than reflection .. There is examples about getter  and setter .. but there is no example for multiple parameterized method like  doSomethig(String a, String b, int c) ;

here is what i am  doing on reflection

> ```
> @Override
> public  T invokeReturn(final Object instance, final Object... args) throws Exception {
>
>     try {
>         final Method mtd = this.getMethod();
>         mtd.setAccessible(getModifierAccessType() != ModifierAccessType.PUBLIC);
>         final Object result = mtd.invoke(instance, args);
>         if (getModifierAccessType() != ModifierAccessType.PUBLIC) {
>             mtd.setAccessible(false);
>         }
>         return (T) result;
>     } catch (final IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
>         logger.error("Error while Invoking Method", ex);
>         throw new Exception(ex.getCause());
>     }
>
> }
> ```

i want to add another method which supports LambdaMetaFactory   here what iam trying

```
@Override
public <T> T callReturn(Object instance, Object... args) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (returnMethod == null) {
            final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.unreflect(method);
            MethodType fncType = this.mtdType();
            MethodType type = this.callMethodType();
            this.returnMethod = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "call", fncType, type, methodHandle, methodHandle.type()).getTarget();
        }

        switch (this.fncType()) {
            case Function: {
                MethodFunction<T> result = (MethodFunction<T>) this.returnMethod.invoke();
                return result.call(instance);
            }
            case FunctionArgs: {
                MethodFunctionArgs<T> result =  (MethodFunctionArgs<T>) this.returnMethod.invoke();
                 Object[] invokeParams = this.getInvokeParams(instance, args);
                return result.call(invokeParams);
            }
            case Void: {
                final VoidFunction result = (VoidFunction) this.returnMethod.invoke();
                result.call(instance);
                return null;
            }
            default: {
                final VoidFunctionArgs result = (VoidFunctionArgs) this.returnMethod.invoke();
                result.call(instance);
                return null;
            }
        }

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

without arguments I dont have any problem on switch  cases  default and Function,  but with arguments i can't run it 
Here is My MethodFunctionArgs @FunctionalInterfaces

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MethodFunctionArgs<T> {

    T call(Object... params) ;
    ///tried too no success
    //T call(Object instance, Object... params) ;
    //VoidFunctionArgs  
    ///void call(Object instance, Object... params);
}
```

Anyway to do that?  there is not a lot of example or  tutorial all is only getter and setter 
maybe there is a way to create dynamic @functionalinterface with varags?

thanx for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t bind an interface with a varargs method to an arbitrary target method, as then, the interface would promise to handle an arbitrary number of arguments while the actual implementation method only accepts a fixed number of arguments. Hence, the following does not compile:

```
public interface MethodFunctionArgs<T> {
    T call(Object... params);
    static String someMethod(String arg1, int arg2) { return ""; }
    // does not work
    MethodFunctionArgs<String> func = MethodFunctionArgs::someMethod;
}
```

What you can do, is the other way round, an implementation method that can handle an arbitrary number of arguments can also handle a request with specific arguments:

```
public interface MethodFunctionArgs<T> {
    T call(String arg1, int arg2);
    static String someMethod(Object... params) { return ""; }
    // no problem
    MethodFunctionArgs<String> func = MethodFunctionArgs::someMethod;
}
```

But it must be mentioned that the `LambdaMetaFactory` is not capable of handling the varargs processing. The compiler helps here by inserting a synthetic helper method, so the compiled code is equivalent to

```
public interface MethodFunctionArgs<T> {
    T call(String arg1, int arg2);
    static String someMethod(Object... params) { return ""; }
    // no problem
    MethodFunctionArgs<String> func = (arg1,arg2) -> someMethod(new Object[]{arg1, arg2});
}
```

But when you have a functional interface with varargs, you are already paying a lot of the typical Reflection costs (boxing, and creating and filling an array) before even invoking the interface method. You may still test the performance of `Method.invoke` compared to `MethodHandle.invoke`:

```
private MethodHandle handle;
public Object callReturn(Object... args) throws Exception {
    try {
        if(handle == null) {
            final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle h = lookup.unreflect(this.getMethod());
            handle = h.asType(h.type().generic())
                      .asSpreader(Object[].class, h.type().parameterCount());
        }
        return handle.invokeExact(args);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex);
    }
}
```

To get a performance benefit from the `LambdaMetaFactory`, you need a specific interface with a matching functional signature.

```
interface SpecialFunction {
    Map<String,SpecialFunction> PREDEFINED = getMap();

    String call(int i, double d, String s);

    static String method1(int i, double d, String s) {
        return "method1("+i+", "+d+", "+s+')';
    }
    static String method2(int i, double d, String s) {
        return "method2("+i+", "+d+", "+s+')';
    }
    static String method3(int i, double d, String s) {
        return "method3("+i+", "+d+", "+s+')';
    }
    /* private  (with Java 9) */ static Map<String,SpecialFunction> getMap() {
        Map<String,SpecialFunction> map = new HashMap<>();
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType invoked = MethodType.methodType(SpecialFunction.class);
        MethodType func = MethodType.methodType(String.class,
                                                int.class, double.class, String.class);
        final int mod = Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.STATIC;
        for(Method m: SpecialFunction.class.getDeclaredMethods()) try {
            MethodHandle target = lookup.unreflect(m);
            if((m.getModifiers()&mod) == mod && target.type().equals(func))
                map.put(m.getName(), (SpecialFunction)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                    lookup, "call", invoked, func, target, func).getTarget().invoke());
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much .  i read your answers.  LambdaMetaFactory  is not sutiable for my use case . because i dont know  what classes  willl be used ( it is creating web routes  from java classes) . so from your experience methodhandle vs reflection which is faster ? ..   which will you prefer methondhandle or reflection method if you were me ?

Comment: @Saltuk usually, methodhandles are faster, however, the best is to try and measure with your actual use case.